# Prevent plane controls (yoke, pedals) from being used as a mouse

Tags: linux

I am using MX Linux.  When I move the yoke / lever plane controls (Saitek, now owned by Logitech), the mouse moves rapidly, making the desktop unusable until the controls are unplugged.  This happens both when the flight simulator is running, and when it's not.

I have the PCI vendor and product IDs of the hardware.  I don't want to blacklist it entirely because I still want to use them with the flight simulator.  How can I prevent them being loaded as mice?

Answer (score 0):

There is a driver called

```
Xserver-Xorg-input-joystick
```

or something like that. It is not needed to use your joystick for games. It does, however, uses your joystick as an input device for the xserver, making it move your mouse.

Uninstall it.